# lxml python 2.5 ElementMaker syntax error

Tags: python, lxml, python-2.6, python-2.5

I have the following code:

```
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker
E = ElementMaker()
params = [E.param('1'), E.param('2')]
E.p( *params, count='2')
```

This works fine in python 2.6, but when I run it with python 2.5, I get the following error:

> ```
> E.p( *params, count='2')
>                   ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

I can't figure out why this is happening. Why does 2.5 throw this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't follow `*` with keyword arguments in Python [before 2.6](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#other-language-changes).  You can try:

```
E.p(*params, **{'count': '2'})
```

or if you'd rather:

```
E.p(*params, **dict(count='2')})
```